# Using Mimekit to send to email addresses that contain special characters

Tags: c#, utf-8, smtpclient, mailkit, mimekit

I am trying to send an email to an email address: coordinación@test.xxxxx.com that contains special characters using Mailkit via a mail server that has  the **SMTPUTF8** extension enabled ( have double checked the same by sending a sample test email from a shell script).

Mailkit reports the exception as "The SMTP server doesn't support the SMTPUTF8 extension", is there something I should be doing to encode the email address differently ?.

I have tried using UTF-8 encoding for the MailboxAddress constructor but the results are the same. Please find the protocol log for the same.

```
Connected to smtp://mail5xx.xx.xxxxx.com:25/?starttls=when-available
S: 220 mail5xx.xx.xxxxx.com ESMTP service ready
C: EHLO [192.xxx.xx.xxx]
S: 250-mail5xx.xx.xxxxx.com says hello
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
S: 250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
S: 250-XACK
S: 250-SIZE 0
S: 250-VERP
S: 250 DSN
```

Edit:
This is no longer a problem for me if I use Mailkit 1.1.4 ( thanks to Jeff for that quick patch), apparently some of the mailservers can send UTF mails even if they don't have the SMTPUTF8 extension enabled, which is strange.

Comment: Please include a [protocol log](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#ProtocolLog) to help diagnose the problem (note: be sure to scrub any `AUTH` commands of any of the base64 data that follows as it will contain your username/password).

Comment: Sorry about that, have included that, is there anything I need to share?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the server response to the `EHLO` command, it does *not* support the `SMTPUTF8` extension.

Note that if it *did* support it, then it would be listed in the response like so:

```
C: EHLO [192.xxx.xx.xxx]
S: 250-mail5xx.xx.xxxxx.com says hello
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
S: 250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN
S: 250-XACK
S: 250-SIZE 0
S: 250-VERP
S: 250-DSN
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
```

Comment: So, is there a way to encode the address and send this ? email @jstedfast?>

Comment: Not that I'm aware of :(

Comment: @Krylor can you confirm that using punycode for the local-part (the part before the '@') of the address works? If so, I'll add that to MimeKit/MailKit.

Comment: Am in the process of testing that, will update as soon as I can see the result!.

Comment: Based on http://rant.gulbrandsen.priv.no/eai/utf8-punycode it looks like using punycode in the local part of the email address is not standardized, but some software uses it (probably because there's no standardized solution when an SMTP server does not support the `SMTPUTF8` extension).

Comment: I can confirm to what he says, it doesn't work on all servers, in fact, I haven't been able to get it ( punycoding of Username) working on my server. There is still the strange case of the whole thing working if I send an email from a Linux webserver running on PHP, I am going to try and provide you access to it, because coordinación@mail..**.**.com is converted to coordinaciÃ³n@mail..**.**.com, not sure what magic that is.

Comment: I have shared the scrubbed raw email from the server on https://pastebin.com/pKY3ZMdg

If you could save that as a .eml file, you should be able to check it using any email client.

Comment: That's just UTF-8, but just because you see UTF-8 in the message headers doesn't mean that's what it provided to the SMTP server in the `MAIL FROM` command :-\

Comment: Ok, here is the SMTP log for the same.
https://pastebin.com/MDHFYiqB

I used an opensource library that's commonly used in PHP, is this of any use?.

Comment: Yea, it looks like it is just ignoring the fact that the smtp server does not support SMTPUTF8 and sending UTF8 anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140168/discussion-between-krylor-and-jstedfast).

Comment: I'll patch MailKit to do the same.

Comment: MimeKit & MailKit 1.14 have been released with this fix.

Comment: Yep, it works like magic, thanks, it certainly solved my problem.